# Showing an alert message for WebService URL Connection Timeout Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-layout, android-intent

I am invoking a webservice url and getting response Successfully in Andriod

here my Code:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    HttpResponse response = null;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // String url=params[0];
    try {

    final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpclient.getParams(), 10000);
    int timeoutSocket = 60*1000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, timeoutSocket);

    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("WebServiceURL");
        response = httpclient.execute(request);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Exaception1>>>","Exaception1>>");        


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("Exaception2>>>","Exaception1>>");

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            out.close();
            responseString = out.toString();
            // Whatever you wanna do with the response
            // Log.d("response", responseString);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("Exaception3>>>","Exaception1>>");

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    } else {
        // Close the connection.
        try {
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return responseString;
}
```

But Some times the WebService URL will not be in Active,My requirement is to Show an alert message to the user for Connection TimeOut ,Could any one help?

Comment: Display alert dialog when your response is not null...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one interface having methods such as success, error and timeout.
catch ConnectTimeoutException into async task and call interface's timeout method.
Handle this timeout method in asyncTask postexecute() or where you executed async task.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch ConnectTimeoutException() in doInBackground so that you can show alert in onPostExecute() of your async task

Answer (score 0):

Catch the `ConnectTimeOutException` in your `doInBackground` and handle the error their

```
catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
```